# How to display syslog priority level in systemd's journalctl

Tags: systemd, journald, journalctl

`journalctl` allows me to filter on priority (`-p`) and color-codes the priority in the output.  But is there any way to get it to output the priority directly, as text?

Comment: See also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408415/distinguishing-levels-in-journalctl) question: "Distinguishing levels in journalctl"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following output options display priority (and facility), but in a different format:

```
journalctl -o verbose
journalctl -o json (and json-pretty)
journalctl -o export
```

Answer (score 1):

```
journalctl --output cat --output-fields MESSAGE,PRIORITY
```

Unfortunately the priority is printed on a line of its own and as number only.